# String iterator never reaches std::string::end()

Tags: c++, string, iterator

When traversing a string using a const iterator, it never ends. The string is never modified during the traverse. But the `itr` will never reach `src.cend()`. Finally the program crashed.

This function is to convert a domain name to a standard domain name for DNS query. For example, `www.abc.com` is converted to `3www3abc3com`.

```
string name_hton(const string &src) {
  string dst;

  auto itr = src.cbegin(), last = itr;

  do {
    while (itr != src.cend() && *itr != '.') {
      ++itr;
    }

    auto diff = itr - last;

    // Push the label length
    dst.push_back(diff);

    // Push the label
    dst.append(last, itr);

    ++itr;
    last = itr;
  } while (itr != src.cend());

  return dst;
}
```

Comment: Time to step through it with your debugger.

Comment: @Nico238 It's not ill-formed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code will go of the end of the string.

When you have found the last `'.'` in the string, and the outer loops iterates your inner loop will end up with `itr == src.cend()`. You will then *increment* that iterator (which is wrong) and the outer loop condition will no longer be true.

You should only do `++itr` in the outer loop if it's not equal to `src.cend()`.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `std::string::find()` instead of a manual search loop:

```
string name_hton(const string &src) {
    string dst;

    auto idx = src.find('.'), last = 0, diff;
    while (idx != string::npos) {
        diff = idx - last;
        dst.push_back(static_cast<char>(diff));
        dst.append(src, last, diff);
        last = idx + 1;
        idx = src.find('.', last);
    }

    diff = src.size() - last;
    dst.push_back(static_cast<char>(diff));
    dst.append(src, last, diff);

    return dst;
}
```